# How can I get rid of ft2font import error from matplotlib on a Windows XP source installation?

Tags: python, windows-xp, matplotlib, importerror

So today I tried building matplotlib from source (git clone) on a Windows XP box.

First I downloaded and compiled the dependencies (zlib, libpng, freetype2) as per [this](http://my.opera.com/hearton965/blog/2011/08/04/building-zlib-libpng-with-mingw) blog entry. I then edited `setup.cfg` to make the matplotlib installation aware of the installations of the dependencies. Lastly, `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` ran without any errors.

But when I try a simple script for a sample plot, I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 53, in <module>
    from matplotlib import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix the issue?

EDIT:

I can find a file called `ft2font.pyd` in the matplotlib folder in the site-packages folder. This file should be able to be imported as per normal, but somehow it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Opening `ft2font.pyd` in [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) showed that `libfreetype-6.dll` was missing as a dependency. Turns out I had forgot to copy `bin\libfreetype-6.dll` to the `system32` folder. After I'd copied it over matplotlib worked without a hitch.