# importerror dll load failed the specified module could not be found when import mpl_toolkits.basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, toolkit

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import mpl_toolkits.basemap
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 23, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 50, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 53, in <module>
    from matplotlib import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Why do I get this exception?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8476108/1982962)?

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't work...

Comment: Your freetype installation is borked.  I don't know anything about windows to tell you how to fix it, but that is your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Anyone else could do me a favor? I used Dependency Walker to try finding missing Dlls, but ended up with 'ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.'